# Send mail in custom hook in directus 9 not working

Tags: javascript, directus

Here is my code for a custom hook that i use to expand directus 9.

I want to send a mail when a specific field in the events table gets updated. For now iÄm only checking if the events table gets updated. Then through the MailService i want to send an email. the code executes and logs 'mail sent' but there is no mail going out.

I have a custom template also which follows after the code. And indeed the template file is picked up and recognized. I check by removing it, then i get an error that the template is missing.

/extensions/hooks/event-time-update/index.js

```
module.exports = function registerHook({ action }, { services, exceptions }) {
  const { MailService } = services;
  const { ServiceUnavailableException, ForbiddenException } = exceptions;

  // Send mail to admin when event time is updated
  action('items.update', async ({ collection }, { schema }) => {
    if (collection !== 'events') return;

    const mailService = new MailService({ schema });

    try {
      await mailService.send({
        to: 'abc@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Event time updated',
        text: 'Event time updated',
        template: {
          name: 'event-time-update',
          data: {
            collection: collection,
          },
        },
      });
      console.log('mail sent');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      throw new ServiceUnavailableException(error);
    }

    return;
  });
};
```

/extensions/templates/event-time-update.liquid

```
    {% layout "base" %}
{% block content %}

<p>
    Die Veranstalungszeit der Veranstaltung <i>{{ projectName }}</i> wurde geändert.
</p>

<p style="text-align: center; padding: 20px 0;">
    <a href="{{ url }}">
        <b>{{ projectName }} ansehen</b>
    </a>
</p>

<p>
    Thank you,<br>
    The {{ projectName }} Team
</p>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay nevermind, it's working. Forgot to replace abc@gmail.com